# How to create a PDF in reStructuredText?

Tags: html, pdf, restructuredtext

The [documentation](https://github.com/lebigot/uncertainties/tree/master/doc) for the [uncertainties Python package](http://packages.python.org/uncertainties/) is written in reStructuredText, for the [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) documentation system.  The HTML [looks fine](http://packages.python.org/uncertainties/).  I would like to create a PDF version.  The goal is to have a "chapter" for each of the web page.

However, what happens is that the PDF generated by the [ReST files](https://github.com/lebigot/uncertainties/tree/master/doc) transforms the (HTML) *sections* of `index.html` into individual *chapters* (which I don't want: the PDF should have them as sections too).  Another problem is that all HTML pages after the main page appear in the PDF as subsections of the section where the `toctree` directive appears (i.e., in the Acknowledgment section of the main page).

So, how should the ReST file be structured so that (1) the web documents look [the same as they are now](http://packages.python.org/uncertainties/), and (2) each web page corresponds to a PDF chapter.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using [rst2pdf](https://code.google.com/p/rst2pdf/)?

Comment: @Ebrahim: I was using `make latex` and `make all-pdf` in Sphinx.

Comment: So give rst2pdf a try if you haven't!

Comment: @Ebrahim: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried it, and realized that it does not recognize Sphinx directives.  The question has been updated to reflect the fact that the HTML version uses Sphinx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is a solution](https://github.com/lebigot/uncertainties/tree/master/doc). If I remember correctly, the key points were:

- Use a special Table of Contents as the master document (I used `index_TOC.rst` instead of the default `index.rst`): in `conf.py`

  - `master_doc = 'index_TOC'`
  - `latex_documents = [('index_TOC', 'uncertaintiesPythonpackage.tex',…]`
- The new Table of Contents file `index_TOC.rst` contains a ToC like

  ```
  TOC
  ===

  .. toctree::
     :hidden:
     :maxdepth: 1

     index
     user_guide
     numpy_guide
     tech_guide
  ```

Thus, the web version still opens onto the main `index.rst` text, and the PDF (LaTeX) version has each ReST file in a separate *chapter*.